# Provide a folder out of source where all my external libraries are found

Tags: python, import

I have the following folder structure

- lib
- my_module

I have moved all the libraries I need into the lib/ folder.

In my `module/__init__.py`, I think I will do:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../lib/')
import my_dependency
```

Then when I need to use this dependency, I will refer to it as

```
my_module.my_dependency
```

Is this a bad usage of Python import?

NOTE: the dependencies consists of some third-party libraries not available via pip/easy_install and some C++ stuff that I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.path.append('../lib/')` assumes that the current working directory is the directory of your script, which may or may not be the case.

A version that doesn't depend on the working directory is:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.split(os.path.split(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))[0])[0], "lib"))
import my_dependency
```

The above in plain language takes the full path to the script, chops off the last two components (script directory and script filename) and appends `lib`.

Answer (score 0):

If the libraries you use are third-party modules—especially popular ones—namespacing them like that is going to get inconsistent pretty fast. You will end up with code that sometimes is referenced as `bar` and sometimes as `foo.bar`. Maintaining such a codebase will not be worth whatever gains you expect to get from prefixing them like that.

If you keep third-party code in your own repository, consider replacing it with a `requirements.txt` file that can be fed to utilities like `easy_install` and `pip`. Both these tools support a `--user` switch that installs to your home directory (not touching system stuff).

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --user
```

Comment: The dependencies are mostly not on easy_install/pip though.

Comment: During development having to do `pip install` for every change in the shared python libraries is going to be a nuisance.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin only if you expect to quickly aggregate a lot of non-popular dependencies (not already installed on the devs' machines).